# How can I get the name of the Textbox in which a function is being run in MS Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to get create a function (or some expression) that can be run from any textbox on a Form, which will return the Name of the textbox as the Value of that textbox, i.e. each box will display it's name in the box itself.

I'm looking for something like Me.ActiveControl.Name, but that only returns the same value for each textbox. Is it possible to be self-referential like that? I haven't been able to find anything that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Cell? self-referential?

The answer is `Me.ActiveControl.Name` which does return the name of the active control (textbox).

That name doesn't change from record to record. If you wish to identify individual records, use the *ID* of the record or the *CurrentRecord* property of the form.

You can make a control the ActiveControl of the form with:

```
Me!TheControlName.SetFocus
```

or:

```
Me.Controls("TheControlName").SetFocus
```

or loop the *Controls* collection of the form to list the textboxes:

```
Dim Control As Control

For Each Control in Me.Controls
    If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        Debug.Print Control.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Do I need to change the focus to each texbox in turn to make that the active control, in order to return its name? Can i do that?

Comment: I would like to have the Control Source of the text box as a function which passes the Name of the textbox (from which the expression is run) to the function i.e. 
=MyFunction(NameoftheControl)
Where the NameoftheControl is obviously the name of the control for that textbox.

If I were to use 
=MyFunction([Name]) it would pass the name of the Form to my function - how do I pass the name of the Textbox (i.e. the control) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but see extended answer, please.